# Place button outside Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, modalviewcontroller, bounds

I would like to add a close button outside the bounds of the modal view controller which I am presenting on an iPad app.

I tried adding a button normally via storyboard, via coding, but the `UIButtons` view gets clipped by the bounds of the modal view controller.

**What my purpose is :** I want to add a close button at the right corner of my modal view controller which is configured as a Form sheet.

I'm launching the modal view controller via a segue from my previous view.

Attached screenshot show what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Required result]

Comment: I solved the question by using the solution described in the link below http://www.cocoaosx.com/2011/10/20/how-to-display-transparent-modal-viewcontrollers/