# How to show UIButton almost out of modalviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to create modalviewcontroller, which should look like this [image]

My problem is in the close button. As you can see in this example it almost out of uiview.

I was tried uiview, who has close button, make transparent but when modalview opens it's still in light gray color.

There is bit of my code :

```
Settings *new = [[Settings alloc]init];
    new.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    //i was change to other presentation styles, but that no I want.
    new.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self presentModalViewController:new animated:YES];


    CGRect r = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 327,
                          self.view.center.y - 255,
                          630, 490);
    r = [self.view convertRect:r toView:new.view.superview.superview];
    new.view.superview.frame = r;
```

If you still don't understand, what I want there is ilustration of modal view I need:
[image]

What is your suggestion, how can I make it?

Comment: How have you tried adding the button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Place button outside Modal View Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105673/place-button-outside-modal-view-controller)

Comment: I put it in the same in "Settings" view.

Comment: Try to add button on window instead of UIViewController...!!!!!

Comment: Consider a new design.